# How to type tree with dynamic field names in typescript

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
interface Tree {
    [key: string]: Tree | {name: string}
}


const t: Tree = {
    b: { name: 'test 1' },
    c: {
        d: { name: 'test 2' }
    },
    e: {
        f: {
            g: { name: 'test 3' }
        }
    }
}

const { b, c, e } = t

const testName1 =  b.name // name
const testName2 =  c.d.name // Error Property 'd' does not exist on type 'Tree | { name: string; }'.  Property 'd' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'.(2339
const testName3 =  e.f.g.name // Error Property 'f' does not exist on type 'Tree | { name: string; }'.  Property 'f' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'.(2339)
```

It's not possible to get access to propperty `c.d` and `e.f`.

What is wrong with the type `Tree` ?

It is possible to use such approach:

```
const { d } =  c as Tree
const testName2 = d.name
```

But might be is there more convenient way ?

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpQig3gKGf5AbQGsIBPALmQGcwpQBzAXSvU2QB9ksQ4BbCFVr0QDAL44JOHAgD2IWsjCsMKALzc8BAEZUsyXgKoBySIoCMx5GIA0W-Aj32C+ACZ6D-QclMRFAJisJF1tnb1wXFxgnSNjkBg9Db19FAGYg5xDnCSk5BTBuZG0bZAQSlDFkDTBpPMUzMAA5L3Mq-G0AOiTkAHoezwEZeXq-Jq9-NtKO1y6vXv6AUSgoWShkAAUVgAdoMDIfVytXWT8DWQKIAA9gRXklMh2fNhQufSShOkYAbmtjDvxNrIdlA9gcjidqGcLtdbiB7o9jG8vB8RAwfmI-gAKfypVIATiG+SUo2aAlSkwgHRgHQYswE82QSxWa0BwNBxhg4NOIHOyCuNwKdz2COenEK7xon1E6L+AO2u32HK5kJ50IFyCFDxQiIG3mE31+HWxuLxAEogA)

Comment: As you already said its dynamic keys, `Tree` type does not know anything about keys a, b, c etc., hence you would not be able to access a, ,b ,c etc keys statically

Comment: Why are you annotating `const t: Tree = ...` instead of just `const t = ...`?  By widening `t` to `Tree` you're explicitly throwing away any more specific structure that `t` might have and all the compiler knows is that it's a `Tree`, and with a random `Tree` you can't just index into it safely like `t.foo.bar.name`.  You'd need runtime tests to check each index for safety.  Do you need help writing these tests?

Comment: @jcalz
Do you mean test like this: `const testName1 = 'd' in c ? c.d.name : ''` ?

Comment: You're going to have to do something like `const testName1 = c && "d" in c && c.d && "name" in c.d && typeof c.d.name === "string" ? c.d.name : "";` given the structure of `Tree`, since you don't know if `c` is defined (what if `t` has no key named `"c"`?), etc.  If you know `t.c.d.name` exists ahead of time then I do wonder why you are widening `t` to `Tree` in the first place.

Comment: @jcalz
> I do wonder why you are widening t to Tree in the first place.
This way I want to tell typescript that leafs ot the tree should have shape `{ name: string }` (not `{ someAnotherPropName: someAnotherPropType }`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is correct: this is an error-prone way to do things. The fact that you annotate it as `t` as `Tree` means that you tell the compiler to forget any specific type information it knows about it and assume it's a generic tree.

This causes a problem: in a generic tree (as you defined it) you have may have subtrees at any points: so c.d may just be a tree itself. If you aren't using it for tree-traversal or something like that and you need to ensure that there is a specific tree structure then you need something different. Also, the way it's defined, you'd have a subtree defined for all possible string keys, nothing left undefined.

If you want to use it for general tree type inputs I'd change your definitions like this and add a type-guard. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpQhAMhONkDeAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcRAvkUaJLIinSZCJZAG0A1hACetBkxDMAurSEoAPmgzZc+TQFcQAEwgxQEI524IA9iAbIwq7cgC8I0gCNaBMpRrIAOSQDgCMgcgcADSiCD6ipEY+flS0wRAOAEwRXKTRogHEpKQw8cXFzMnkqUEhYMgAzDkJkaJcHOxEMIYIYMB2yMB0OHgAFABucAA2zsKaaiN6yIYmZiAWAJS0k1ODdFqYi4Rwohhg+lAgyACE1zvIAGQPjtIADhA2+DsAdNUorgDkAAieQsIHsLhEWz2eq+TxRZAIBEoDhuRzcYD4UZDRajTwbDYeRF2Og2KYQb5TGzMPG-fwbCEYrEIR7Pa443SjBCEp57XEIb5GAlE6EOOoAOX8mTRiMFdKoyAA9IrkOKbMgqYpoMg4FdoFAbFArEA)

```
interface TreeLeaf {
  name: string;
}

interface Tree {
  [key: string]: Tree | TreeLeaf | undefined
}

const t: Tree = {
  b: { name: 'test 1' },
  c: {
    d: { name: 'test 2' }
  },
  e: {
    f: {
      g: { name: 'test 3' }
    }
  }
};

function isLeaf(val: Tree | TreeLeaf | undefined): val is TreeLeaf {
  return !!val && typeof val.name === "string";
}

const { b, c, e } = t

if (isLeaf(b)) {
  console.log(b.name);
}

if (c && !isLeaf(c) && isLeaf(c.d)) {
  const testName2 =  c.d.name // No longer an error
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I can't understand why this expression is ok for typescript:
 ```const { b, c, e } = t

const testName1 =  b.name // OK```.

Comment: That's because `t` is defined as a `Tree`, which - by the your original definitions - had a subtree or leaf defined for any string, including `b`. So you can access `b`. It's either a tree that has something defined for all strings including `name`, or a leaf, that has a string instead. So you can access `b.name`, with the caveat that you don't know if it's a string or not.

Comment: Got it. Thanx a lot.